# Can't insert on mongoDB Atlas with Node.js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently trying to learn mongoDB, this is my first time doing it and I'm stuck.

On my index.js file, where I've all my NodeJs configurations, I made the connection to the db successfully but I'm not able to make an insert of the data of the user inputs from the HTML.

Here is the index.js file:

```
const path = require("path");

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

const port = 8080;

const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://mongodbURI";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

app.post("/new", (req, res) => {
  let myObj = [
    {
      name: req.body.usrName,
      email: req.body.usrMail,
      age: req.body.usrAge,
      password: req.body.usrPassword
    }
  ];
  client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("GetForm").collection("UserData");
    collection.insertOne(myObj, function(err, r) {
      console.log("Added a user");
      res.redirect("/");
    });
    client.close();
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Runing On Port ${port}`);
});
```

And here my index.html form:

```
<form
 action="/new"
 method="POST"
 enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>
  <label for="usrName">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="usrName" id="usrName" />
  <label for="usrMail">Email: </label>
  <input type="email" name="usrMail" id="usrMail" />
  <label for="usrAge">Age: </label>
  <input type="number" name="usrAge" id="usrAge" />
  <label for="usrPassword">Password: </label>
  <input type="password" name="usrPassword" id="usrPassword" />
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

I'll be glad if someone could help me!

Comment: Let me know which error you are facing now.

Comment: @tpikachu there's no error, that's the weirdest thing for me, it even show the message ```added user``` that is supposed to be shown if everithing is fine, but when I go to mongodb there is no input being inserted.

Comment: let myObj = [
    {
      name: req.body.usrName,
      email: req.body.usrMail,
      age: req.body.usrAge,
      password: req.body.usrPassword
    }
  ];

Comment: Please remove this []

Comment: For the insertOne. This should be not an array. Should be one object.

Comment: @tpikachu cool, I'll try that! thanks!

Comment: Is it working? And I upgraded the answer )

Comment: @tpikachu I've just tried that but sadly it's still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206023/discussion-between-tpikachu-and-facu-carbonel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual code has few issues :

**Working code :**

```
app.post("/new", (req, res) => {
    let myObj = {
        name: req.body.usrName,
        email: req.body.usrMail,
        age: req.body.usrAge,
        password: req.body.usrPassword
    };
    client.connect((err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("cannot connect db" + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("DataBase connection made successfully");
        const collection = db.db().collection("UserData");

        collection.insertOne(myObj, function (err, r) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("cannot add obj");
                return;
            }

            console.log("Added a user");
            res.redirect("/");
        });
        client.close();
    });
});
```

**Issues with the code :**

```
const path = require("path");

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

const port = 8080;

const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://mongodbURI";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

app.post("/new", (req, res) => {
  let myObj = [
    {
      name: req.body.usrName,
      email: req.body.usrMail,
      age: req.body.usrAge,
      password: req.body.usrPassword
    }
  ];
  client.connect(err => { // You've missing err check here, you need to return if there is an error.
    const collection = client.db("GetForm").collection("UserData"); 
    /** From above line db(GetForm) is not needed if you're connecting to GetForm, your url directly connects to database :: GetForm as it ends with /GetForm.
        Also other major issue is MongoDB driver would give you client on `client.connect` function, So to access database you need to do client.db() */
    collection.insertOne(myObj, function(err, r) {
      console.log("Added a user");
      res.redirect("/");
    });
    client.close();
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Runing On Port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved it with the help of @srinivasy and @tpikachu.
I changed the `app.post` method from this:

```
app.post("/new", (req, res) => {
  let myObj = [
    {
      name: req.body.usrName,
      email: req.body.usrMail,
      age: req.body.usrAge,
      password: req.body.usrPassword
    }
  ];
  client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("GetForm").collection("UserData");
    collection.insertOne(myObj, function(err, r) {
      console.log("Added a user");
      res.redirect("/");
    });
    client.close();
  });
});
```

To this:

```
app.post("/new", (req, res) => {
  let myObj = {
    name: req.body.usrName,
    email: req.body.usrMail,
    age: req.body.usrAge,
    password: req.body.usrPassword
  };
  client.connect((err, db) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("cannot connect db" + err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("DataBase connection made successfully");
    const collection = db.db().collection("UserData");

    collection.insertOne(myObj, function(err, r) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("cannot add obj");
        return;
      }

      console.log("Added a user");
      res.redirect("/");
    });
    client.close();
  });
});
```

And luckily now it's working fine! Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Yes there are couple of minor issues with your code which is why it didn't work, Do you wanted me to put an answer explaining all why that piece of code didn't work for reference 
?

Comment: It will be nice if you do it, I've solved it and the code in this answer is the final result but it will be nice for future reference if someone gets stuck in something similar to have a better solution than mine.